# Jobeet Day 3, doctrine:data-load problem

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, jobeet

I'm trying to load data from fixtures jobs.yaml and categories.yaml with this command:

```
$ php symfony doctrine:data-load
```

But the tables are empty. I have got the columns and tables created, but no data loaded.

It returns:

```
doctrine  Loading data fixtures from "./jobeet/data/fixtures"
doctrine  Data was successfully loaded
```

And the source files were copied and pasted from the tutorial.

```
# data/fixtures/categories.yml
JobeetCategory:
  design:
    name: Design
  programming:
    name: Programming
  manager:
    name: Manager
  administrator:
    name: Administrator
```

And:

```
# data/fixtures/jobs.yml
JobeetJob:
  job_sensio_labs:
    JobeetCategory: programming
    type:         full-time
    company:      Sensio Labs
    logo:         sensio-labs.gif
    url:          http://www.sensiolabs.com/
    position:     Web Developer
    location:     Paris, France
    description:  |
      You've already developed websites with symfony and you want to work
      with Open-Source technologies. You have a minimum of 3 years
      experience in web development with PHP or Java and you wish to
      participate to development of Web 2.0 sites using the best
      frameworks available.
    how_to_apply: |
      Send your resume to fabien.potencier [at] sensio.com
    is_public:    true
    is_activated: true
    token:        job_sensio_labs
    email:        job@example.com
    expires_at:   '2010-10-10'

  job_extreme_sensio:
    JobeetCategory:  design
    type:         part-time
    company:      Extreme Sensio
    logo:         extreme-sensio.gif
    url:          http://www.extreme-sensio.com/
    position:     Web Designer
    location:     Paris, France
    description:  |
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
      enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in.

      Voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    how_to_apply: |
      Send your resume to fabien.potencier [at] sensio.com
    is_public:    true
    is_activated: true
    token:        job_extreme_sensio
    email:        job@example.com
    expires_at:   '2010-10-10'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the fixtures? My guess is, that there is something wrong with the indentation.

Comment: Indentation problems would likely throw an error --- I think it does so everywhere else.

Comment: Are your files suffixed with the .yaml or is it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, my files were named with .yaml extension and doctrine didn't recognize them, it must be .yml

Thanks!